# Deficiencies of Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm currently self-studying measure theory and had a question regarding the Riemann integral. This example is from Axler's MIRA (Measure, Integration & Real Analysis).

**First Question:**

Let $r_1, r_2,...$ be a sequence that includes each rational number in [0,1] exactly once and that includes no other numbers. For $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, define $f_{k}: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by

\begin{equation}
f_{k}(x)=
\begin{cases} 
    1 & \text{if } x \in \{r_1,r_2,...,r_k\} \\
    0 &  \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Then each $f_k$ is Riemann integrable and $\int_{0}^{1}f_k = 0$.

I understand that each $f_k$ is Riemann integrable since the lower Riemann integral is trivially $0$ (there are irrationals in [0,1]), and the upper Riemann integral is also $0$ considering every possible partitions (you can make the partition tight enough that the region including $r_k$ will have area of $\epsilon$ small.)

Since the lower Riemann integral equals the upper Riemann integral, each $f_k(x)$ is Riemann integrable. The problem is, I don't know how to write this in a formal manner, and not sure if my intuition is even correct.

**Second Question:**

Define $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ by

\begin{equation}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if x is rational},
\\
0 & \text{if x is irrational}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Clearly, $\lim_{k \to \infty} f_k(x) = f(x)$ for each $x \in [0,1]$.

However, $f$ is not Riemann integrable as seen before.

My question is how is each $f_k$ Riemann integrable, but $f$ is not Riemann integrable. Does it have to do with $f_k$ only having finitely many rational numbers that have function value 1 and $f$ has infinitely many rational numbers that result in function value 1?

Any help or insights will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to the first question:** You can use the theorem that says the function is Riemann integrable iff the set of discontinuities of that function has a Lebesgue measure equal to 0. Since you have a finite set, it has a Lebesgue measure 0.

---

**Answer to the second question:** The set of discontinuities of the given function is interval $[0,1]$, which has a Lebesgue measure equal to $1\neq 0$, therefore, by using previous theorem, it is not a Riemann integrable function.

Comment: This is using a cannon to kill a fly.

Comment: It can also be done by choosing rational and irrational partitions for the second question and an arbitrary partition for the first one, but it would take much time to write it down in LaTeX. Maybe this will help.

Comment: No. Think about upper and lower sums.

Comment: For the first one, every lower Riemann sums will be 0 since every nonempty interval will consist of irrationals. But what about the upper Riemann sum?

Comment: @VukJovovic Thanks for the answer, but I haven't learned anything about Lebesgue measures. This example is from the very beginning of the book talking about how Riemann integral is not good enough for rich theory of integration.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, that's what I meant, I have just constructed that answer poorly.

Answer (score 0):

For the second, show that every upper sum is $1$ and every lower sum is $0$. So $f$ is very not-integrable.

For the first, take a partition with tiny intervals containing each of $r_1,\dots,r_k$, the sum of whose lengths is $<\epsilon$. Then $\int_0^1 f_k(x)\,dx = 0$, since the inf of the set of upper sums is $0$.